# How to write a web service in php?

Tags: php, web-services

I am trying to write a simple web service for a function I wrote in php that I am going to provide for another server. I have never done it and have no clue where and how to start it. I tried some websites but, got lost in the middle. Does anyone know a simple document, template, website, example,... so I can quick start?

Comment: please give a little more explanation of what you're trying to do

Comment: To let you know, it's just the same as any other web application. No difference. Process input data and print out result.

Comment: This is a very open question, I'm not saying it is bad, but it can be approached in many ways. It would be good if you could comment the answers to let people know what you want.

Comment: An external app is sitting on server A & my code for authentication sitting on server B. Server A is running xbox game & a C# code will communicate with server B via a web service. My code is in php & handling the authentication,saving, & retrieving data without any problem separately.I am trying to provide this to server A using web-service. I dont know how does it work & where to start from. How can I have server A sends info to server B using the web-service & receive data. I've never done that. I hope this answer clarifies what is in my mind and what I am trying to accomplish. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a very simple JSON/JSONP API without libraries.

Here's a very basic example where you'd take an array of data, then JSON encode that array and returns the JSON, or JSONP, depending on the request:

```
$data = array();
//....do something to prepare your data....

if(isset($_GET['callback'])) {
    $callback = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9\.]/", '', $_GET['callback']);
    header("Content-type: application/javascript");
    echo $callback . "(" . json_encode($data) . ");";
}
else{
    header("Content-type: application/json");
    echo json_encode($data); //JSON
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a great tutorial when i start writing my own web service.  [David Walsh FTW!](http://davidwalsh.name/web-service-php-mysql-xml-json)

It uses PHP/MySQL with outputs being in JSON and/or XML

Answer (score 2):

Which resources have you tried to follow? There's a good article on [Developing Web Services Using PHP](http://onlamp.com/pub/a/php/2007/07/26/php-web-services.html) on the O'Reilly PHP Devcenter that's fairly comprehensive and easy to follow.

Answer (score 2):

So, essentially a REST service?

Basically, you need a script that sits on the server and waits for something to call it, either with or without input, depending on whether or not you need to send information to it for processing or if it just returns information without filters or whatever.  Processing the information looks much like processing a form from a local page, since you'll probably send requests in GET or POST with cURL, though you could also do something like file_get_contents("http://www.server.com/RESTscript.php?id=23") if using $_GET.

When a request comes in, the script takes the info sent and processes it and returns the information, probably in JSON format with json_encode()/json_decode() or XML format, which the script which called the REST service would then have to do whatever you want with it.

So, for a small, quick, dirty and static example:

```
//You would use whatever scripting to build the needed array
//Also, note that the only output on the script should be what is being returned to the caller
$requested = array('id' => 23, 'name' => 'John Smith', 'info' => 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');
echo json_encode($requested);
```

and the calling script would do something like this:

```
$request = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://www.server.com/REST.php?optional=value"));
```

which would make $request an array the same as $requested, or it might make it an stdobj, not sure, forget which.  Either way, easy to work with.  That's all it takes, about as simple and useless a web service as you can get.

Answer (score 1):

> To let you know, it's just the same as any other web application. No difference. Process >input data and print out result. – Col. Shrapnel 5 secs ago

1-Accept input
2-Process input
3-Return result

1- Accept input. your code is pretty much treated as a form and the info is passed to it to act on with a web request

2- Process Input - play with the input however you need to to come up with the result to return

3- Return result - spit back the results similar to how you would output an html page from php although format it like the calling system expects (html, json, etc)

Answer (score 0):

There are a good number of [PEAR](http://pear.php.net/packages.php?catpid=23&catname=Web+Services) libraries on this, one of them may fit your needs nicely.